# The apc.php stats page from APC (PHP cache) is showing wrong file sizes

Tags: php, file, size, apc

When I go to the apc.php stats page and click on "System Cache Entries" or "User Cache Entries," the sizes shown for the files are about ten times larger than they actually are.  Is this an error in how the file sizes are calculated?

Answer (score 0):

For System Cache Entries, the size shown is the size of bytecode, not of the PHP script file. For User Cache Entries, the size shown is that of the zval structure that holds the value.

Comment: Just curious - why would the file be so much larger? Shouldn't the size in bytecode be smaller than the filesize?

Comment: Can't answer that, I don't know the innards of PHP well enough to explain why the bytecode should be larger!